# Loading External .js file that requires jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, scriptmanager

So there I am trying to load an external .js file which in return loads other pages using $.ajax and jQuery Templates. Everything was working when my code was all in a single .aspx page. But after distributing everything to separate clean files I am having this error:

## Default.aspx

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.min.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jQuery.tmpl.min.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Pages/Templates/Stream/Stream.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

## Stream.js

```
GetStream();

 function GetStream() {
        alert('ok'); 
        $.ajax({ /* It reaches this line */
        type: 'POST',
```

But returns the following.

```
$ is undefined
```

Please note that I have added the Stream.js file seperately without using the `ScriptManagerProxy` below the jquery-1.7 file. And still got the same thing. Ideas?

**I forgot to mention that the content of Stream.js is wrapped in**:

```
$(document).ready(function () { });
```

Comment: "$ is undefined error" is happening becouse your jquery code run before jquert included to your site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the benefit of using the script manager for this? It's just going to format/output HTML  tags.. Why not use HTML instead.

```
<script language="javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="/Scripts/jQuery.tmpl.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="/Pages/Templates/Stream/Stream.js"></script>
```

Comment: I sort of need the provided function pageLoad() that also executes and rebinds jquery selectors on partial postbacks.

Comment: Yes, but the Stream.js file is required on this page only and I'm trying not to load it on all my pages.

Comment: At the top of this partial, just add the script tag for Steam.js. You can embed `<script>` tags anywhere that's convenient, not just the `<head>`

Answer (score 0):

You should reference the external file in the ScriptManagerProxy to make sure they're executed in the correct order.

Comment: Hey SLaks thanks for the answer. I am referencing Stream.js in the ScriptManagerProxy Script References.

Comment: Well the `undefined` error and please see this http://www.jeffreyramia.com/firebug.png